# Character Counter for multiple text areas

Tags: javascript, html, forms, counter

I have a form that has 3 text areas, a copy button, and a reset button. I want to add all the characters to one sum, then display that sum next to the copy/reset button. There is a 500 character limit, and the counter should start at 49 characters. Should I just take all my textareas and "Funnel" them into a var, then count that var? I'm not sure how I should approach this. I've tried [this technique](https://inkplant.com/code/count-textarea-characters-with-javascript)

but it only works with one text area, not the sum of all. If the char count goes above 500, I'd like the text to turn red and say "you've gone over your character limit." I do not want to restrict or limit the text once its over 500. I'm a little fried trying to find a solution, and I'm an obvious html/javascript novice.

I do not need to worry about the carriage return issue in firefox/opera since everyone will be using IE11.

```
<h1>
     Enter your notes into the text boxes below
</h1>

         <p>
           Please avoid using too many abbreviations so others can read your notes. 
    </p>



<form>

    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    // input field descriptions
    var desc = new Array();
    desc['kcall'] = 'Reason for Call';
    desc['pact'] = 'Actions Taken';
    desc['mrec'] = 'Recommendations';




    function CopyFields(){
        var copytext = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
        copytext += desc[arguments[i]] + ': ' + document.getElementById (arguments[i]).value + '\n';
    }
    var tempstore = document.getElementById(arguments[0]).value;
    document.getElementById(arguments[0]).value = copytext;
    document.getElementById(arguments[0]).focus();
    document.getElementById(arguments[0]).select();
    document.execCommand('Copy');
    document.getElementById(arguments[0]).value = tempstore;  

   document.getElementById("copytext").reset();

}
    --></script>


<p> Reason For Call: </p> <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="kcall"></textarea><br>
<p> Actions Taken:   </p> <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="pact"></textarea><br>
<p> Recommendations: </p> <textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="mrec"></textarea><br>
<br>

<button type="button" onclick="CopyFields('kcall', 'pact', 'mrec');">Copy Notes</button>



    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is a little more tricky that you think, and is not cause the complex of count the number of character inside of a `textarea` thats is actually pretty simple. in jquery:

```
   $("textarea").each(function(index, item){
        sum += $(this).val().length;
    });
```

The problem begins whit the keyup event since and how you manage that event, in my follow example, I pretty much manage when the user press the key like in `regular state` but if you start holding a key then stoping and copy and paste really quick, the event get lost a little bit and recover after the second keyup. Any way here is my full example with count of `character counter`, change from red to black and black to red if you `over pass` the max characters and validation for `submit or not` the form

[image]

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/t535famp/

HTML

```
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<button class="reset"></button>
You have use <span class="characters"></span> of <span class="max"></span>
<button class="submit">submit</button>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

    var counter = 0; //you can initialize it with any number
    var max =  400; //you can change this

    var $characters = $(".characters");
    var $max = $(".max");
    var submit = true;

    $characters.html(counter);
    $(".max").html(max);

    function count(event){

        var characters = $(event.target).val().length;

        $characters.html(counter);

        //sum the textareas
        var sum = 0;
        $("textarea").each(function(index, item){
            sum += $(this).val().length;
        });

        counter = sum;

        if(counter > max) {
            $characters.css({ color : "red" });
            submit = false;
        }else{
            $characters.css({ color : "black" });
            submit = true;
        }
    }

    $(document).on("keyup","textarea",count);

    $(document).on("click",".submit",function(){
        if(submit)
            alert("done");
        else
            alert("you have more characters than " + max);
    });
})
```

Good luck my 2 cents

Comment: Why include a library that isn't tagged or asked for?

Comment: I expect very, very few get paid to post here so everyone does it in their free time. It's not considered good etiquette to introduce libraries or dependencies that aren't asked for in the question or tagged. You've also introduced a number of issues the OP doesn't need to deal with such as keyup, which isn't mentioned in the question, other answers or comments, and code like `$(this).val()`, which is an inefficient alternative to `this.value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function textareaLength() {
    var charCount = 0;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'), function (textarea) { charCount += textarea.value.length; });
    return charCount;
}
```

That will return the count of all textareas on the page. Change the querySelector to be more specific if you only want to count specific textareas.

One option would be to add onchange events to your textareas which call a function like below:

```
<script>
    function validate() { 
        if(textareaLength() >= 500) {
            //limit reached
        }
    }


    function textareaLength() {
        var charCount = 0;
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'), function (textarea) { charCount += textarea.value.length; });
        return charCount;
    }
</script>
<textarea onchange="validate()"></textarea>
<textarea onchange="validate()"></textarea>
<textarea onchange="validate()"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the button is in the same form as the textarea elements, you can get a reference to the form using the button's *form* property. You can also get all the text area elements in the form using *querySelectorAll*, then loop over them, adding up the characters in each.

The following just counts the total number of characters in the textarea elements:

```
<button type="button" onclick="count(this)">Copy Notes</button>
```

and the function:

```
function count(el) {
  var tas = el.form.querySelectorAll('textarea');
  var numChars = 0;
  for (var i=0, iLen=tas.length; i<iLen, I++) {
    numChars += tas[i].value.length;
  }
  return numChars;
}
```

If you can rely on ES5+ methods, then you can do:

```
function count(el) {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(el.form.querySelectorAll('textarea'),
    function(numChars, ta){return numChars += ta.value.length}, 0); 
}
```

Note that by convention, functions starting with a capital letter are reserved for constructors, so *CopyFields* should be *copyFields*.

Here's a working example:

```js
function count(el) {
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(el.form.querySelectorAll('textarea'),
    function(numChars, ta){return numChars += ta.value.length}, 0); 
}
```

```html
<form>

  <textarea name="ta0"></textarea>
  <textarea name="ta1"></textarea>
  <textarea name="ta2"></textarea><br>
  <input type="text" name="numChars">
  <button type="button" onclick="this.form.numChars.value = count(this)">count</button>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Count

Here's a really simple function:

```
function TextLength() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(
              document.querySelectorAll('textarea'),
              function(b,a) { return b+a.value.length }, 0);
}
```

Or with ES6:

```
const TextLength = () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).reduce((b,a) => b + a.value.length, 0)
```

To use this:

```
TextLength();
```

---

## Change

Now add this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'), function (e) { e.oninput = TextLength });
```

And again, ES6:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('textarea')).forEach(e => e.oninput = TextLength );
```

Comment: Let's say I wanted to stick with ES6, would I add the "const TextLength" part inside my current script? Then I would put the array?

I guess I'm just confused where to place everything you typed.

Comment: @slightlydrifting Yes, this will automatically do it for all textareas

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one `textarea` (Multiple) and you want to display character count on each `textarea`, you may try below code, as its working me like a charm.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('textarea').on("load propertychange keyup input paste",
        function () {     
            var cc = $(this).val().length;
            var id=$(this,'textarea').attr('id');
            $('#'+id).next('p').text('character Count: '+cc); 
        });
      
      $('textarea').trigger('load');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="one">hello</textarea>
<p></p>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
<p></p>
<textarea id="three"></textarea>
<p></p>
```